# Xcode device Unavailable, runtime profile not found

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode8

In the following environment:

```
Xcode 8.3.2
react-native-cli 2.0.1
react-native: 0.44.0
macOS Sierra 10.12.5
```

Just updated Xcode and macOS to run React Native and keep on practicing as I was some days ago... but everytime I try to run:

```
react-native run-ios
```

I get the error:

```
Scanning 555 folders for symlinks in /Users/juangarcia/projects/react-tests/CountDown/node_modules (6ms)
Found Xcode project CountDown.xcodeproj

Could not find iPhone 6 simulator
```

I try to see the list of devices available and I get:

```
~/projects/react-tests/CountDownSample » xcrun simctl list devices
== Devices ==
-- iOS 10.3 --
-- tvOS 10.2 --
    Apple TV 1080p (323FA90C-0366-4B5B-AEEE-D0477C61762A) (Shutdown)
-- watchOS 3.2 --
    Apple Watch - 38mm (F42C0C0D-325B-41DD-948D-E44B0A08B951) (Shutdown)
    Apple Watch - 42mm (75D8BAF1-27CB-47EE-9EE3-D400B962F8BC) (Shutdown)
    Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm (64D01BD4-5C37-4885-A73A-52479D9CCF4F) (Shutdown)
    Apple Watch Series 2 - 42mm (8471C9FD-BCF3-4DDC-B386-F17E128C5EB1) (Shutdown)
-- Unavailable: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-3 --
    iPhone 4s (1FF2D0D3-F136-43A7-8148-7B1849A7B1E3) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 5 (859D4D90-F1B5-4DE8-B976-6984F85CAFE3) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 5s (5B2AD8CD-9B3F-413C-BF16-FA96F807BB2B) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 6 (2573D214-4371-47A8-BFF6-3341862954E0) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 6 Plus (8916CD9B-4D8B-463F-8583-75A2CE4F61FD) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 6s (41093980-7912-4F98-9D06-981A533FAAFE) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 6s Plus (6A85D2AE-D867-4341-979C-FEE8308DE93E) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad 2 (BFBB5477-B6D9-48C3-B529-516D2D9105A7) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad Retina (C49B5920-F4FF-4D7F-AA74-7AE2367FF09D) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad Air (4101FC8E-D8B9-4496-AD2B-1484661C15DE) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad Air 2 (9952B05C-829F-428F-AC76-EB1F8FB55D72) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad Pro (735082E2-4470-4D9A-BAA1-BEDA8426B725) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
-- Unavailable: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-9-2 --
    Apple TV 1080p (AD48DE24-6295-4EFC-9787-A9B5D8118503) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
-- Unavailable: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-2-2 --
    Apple Watch - 38mm (C3F2A7C3-3967-4159-9B79-13CBA63E399E) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    Apple Watch - 42mm (656005A9-7555-4872-A7FB-FB6BCB65139C) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
```

react takes by default Iphone 6 to work with, and it is not available

**how can I make it available again? and why did this happen?**

Comment: Can you please check iPhone6 simulator is there in system? I got same issue. But I restart system, it will work for me.

Comment: Do they show in Xcode? To the right of the run button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

pfff it was simpler than expected... when installing SO and Xcode, by some reason, the whole list of devices where removed... going to Xcode UI menu adding a new simulator in this case iPhone 6 was enough... I tried restarting and going back, and so on did not know there was an option in UI for this as I am new to XCode environment. thx for the answers.

In the XCode menu, Window --> Devices --> Add the new simulator...

Answer (score 19):

TL;DR:

Upgrade unavailable simulators to the latest (or the desired) iOS runtime using `xcrun simctl upgrade`

Details:

I was in this situation probably after performing a `xcrun simctl delete unavailable` with both Xcode 10 and Xcode 11 installed (and Xcode 10 as currently active).

Executing `xcrun simctl list runtimes` I found the iOS 13.1 runtime listed:

```
iOS 11.4 (11.4 - 15F79) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-4
iOS 13.1 (13.1 - 17A844) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-1
tvOS 13.0 (13.0 - 17J585) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-13-0
watchOS 6.0 (6.0 - 17R575) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-6-0
```

But when I executed `xcrun simctl list`, several simulators are listed as unavailable:

```
    iPhone 8 Plus (B08025C1-B7A2-40C0-B6D5-517EC8BB3C45) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone Xs (0A1C1EAA-8E18-4508-9E14-C376D944984B) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone Xs Max (84C692F5-6CF3-449D-B166-0EA26B1FAC4B) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone Xʀ (7581E116-5CFB-4A94-94A0-30B5B8871874) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
```

My solution was to upgrade the unavailable simulators to the desired iOS runtime (iOS 13.1 in my case):

`xcrun simctl upgrade SIMULATOR_ID "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-1"`

To avoid having to perform this manually for all simulators I wrote this small ruby script to upgrade all the iPhones at once:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

uuid_regex = /([0-9A-Z]{8}-[0-9A-Z]{4}-[0-9A-Z]{4}-[0-9A-Z]{4}-[0-9A-Z]{12})/
unavailable_iPhones = `xcrun simctl list | grep iPhone | grep "runtime profile not found"`.split("\n")
unavailable_iPhones.each do | row |
    uuid = row.match(uuid_regex).captures.first
    system("xcrun simctl upgrade #{uuid} \"com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-1\"")
end
```

Comment: Wait, so you upgraded the os version of all the simulators to iOS 13.1?

Comment: No, only those which were listed as "unavailable"...

Answer (score 15):

I had this issue in xCode 9 and 10.2.
[image: g em]

For others that ends up here with the same problem, here is what helped me:

1. Close xCode
2. Restart your laptop (I know it is huge bummer)
3. Open xCode and run the build again

Comment: I had this issue after updating to Xcode 12, quitting Xcode and the simulator fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I went to 
node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js

And i've replaced:

`if (version.indexOf('iOS') !== 0 )`

with

`if (!version.includes("iOS" ))`

And

`if (simulator.availability !== '(available)')`

with

`if (simulator.isAvailable !== true)`

Answer (score 1):

Missing ios14 simulator option in Xcode 12 beta 4 workaround:

Check out this fantastic article about `simctl`.

I created an iOS14 sim since the XC12-beta4 was not giving me a download / create option via:

`xcrun simctl create <name> <device> <os>`

ex.

`xcrun simctl create iPhone-8Plus-14 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-8-Plus com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-0`

Answer (score 1):

If you have or have had multiple versions of Xcode open, you may need to reboot or completely re-install the `CoreSimulatorService`, an evil, globally installed background service that somehow remains online and available to many versions of Xcode despite it being compatible with only one version.

See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72946533/731285

Other symptoms of this issue: Simulators not showing up in the `Window > Devices and Simulators` listing and the following:

- [Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52489500/731285)
- [Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS. Failed to boot device iPhone Xs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57680140/encountered-an-error-communicating-with-ibagent-ios-failed-to-boot-device-iphon/72953538#72953538)