# debugserver is x86_64 binary running in translation, attached failed. Could not attach to pid :

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arm

I just shifted my Xcode project from my Intel Mac to Apple M1 Chip. The code is compiled successfully on M1 Chip but once I tried to run it on simulator it shows the following error.

```
debugserver is x86_64 binary running in translation, attached failed.
```

[image: Xcode simulator Error]

I have checked the **"Open using Rosettea"** option for Xcode but **it still not running M1 machine**.

Comment: Hey! Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue. The build won't succeed without using Rosetta and it will fail to attach if I use Rosetta.

Comment: No man, still finding the solution.

Comment: @QaziAmmar were you able to solve this issue, I am having same but none of the answers helping. I am having Mac Intel machine and simulator is not getting attached to xcode in debug mode.

Comment: No @Mrunal, still looking for the solution.

Comment: Same here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74366053/xcode-14-is-not-getting-attached-to-simulator-in-debug-mode

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With Mac M1 you could also exclude arm64 in your target

Target > Build Settings > Excluded Architectures --> add "arm64"

If an update isn’t available from the vendor, temporarily use the EXCLUDED_ARCHS build setting to exclude arm64 for the simulator SDK as shown in the figure below. Do not exclude arm64 for any other SDK.

[image: change this setting only for iOS Simulator]

Comment: "arm64e" was already there. However changing it into "arm64" did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Thermech if we exclude arm64 there will be any problem with the app ?

Comment: @ArshadShaik To avoid any impact, you could exclude it only for iosSimulator like proposed by Apple here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3117-resolving-build-errors-for-apple-silicon#Update-pre-compiled-libraries-from-vendors

Answer (score 27):

I had a problem running watchOS simulator.

**Solution that worked for me:**

- Quit Xcode
- Right click on Xcode, press "Get Info"
- **Make sure that "Open using Rosetta" is not selected**(see image)
- Delete derived data(don't know if this is required)
- Reopen Xcode and run your app

[image: img1]

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that I have tried with both while selecting and unselecting the "Open using Roseeta" its now working.

Comment: ok, if it is working now, you can share your solution with others :D

Comment: No its not working for me with both scenarios

Comment: then probably you mistyped `its now working.` instead of `its not working.` :D

Comment: yes its a typo. I have to type  its not working

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the same issue trying to open the Apple Watch Simulator, but I was able to fix it by disabling Rosetta in the xcode.

Mac M1
Xcode 13.4.1
WatchOs 8.5

Comment: Once I uncheck the rosetta Xcode is not able to make a build.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming its not solved yet, can you try the following and let us know -

**Solution 1**

It's an issue with authorization. Try this in the Terminal:

```
sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable
```

It may ask you to enter your mac password so kindly do that.

**Solution 2**

Edit Scheme -> Run -> Debug executable

uncheck this checkbox it will be ok!

Comment: second option worked for me. May I know what `Debug excitable` usually does?

Comment: Uncheck `Debug executable` works for me.

Comment: The “Debug executable” checkbox specifies whether or not you want to run with the debugger enabled. Once running, you can use Debug > Attach to Process on a process that has been launched with debugging disabled if needed. #ThinkAndCode

Comment: This is a bad idea. Your debugger will no longer work.

Answer (score 1):

I also updated Xcode to 14.0 and MacOS to Ventura, I was getting a similar message.

[image: main_issue]

The problem for me was my team member accidentally selected "Wait for the executable to be launched" in our scheme settings. Changing it to "Automatically", worked for me.

Click on your scheme to reveal your schemes and scheme settings.

[image: demo_scheme]

Click on **Edit Scheme**, located at the bottom.

Select the **Run** option on the left and select **Automatically** on the **Launch** section.

[image: run_scheme]

Comment: Any way to resolve this error while keeping "Wait for the executable to be launched" ticked?

Comment: Here I already had the setting adjusted to "Automatically" but still fails with the same error...

Answer (score 1):

Im using macOS M1 Pro, XCode 14.2

I had a problem running iOS simulator.

Solution that worked for me:

Solution 1 (uncheck Rosetta on Xcode 14.2)

- Quit Xcode
- Right click on Xcode, press "Get Info"
- Make sure that "Open using Rosetta" is not selected(see image)
- Delete derived data(don't know if this is required)
- Reopen Xcode and run your app

Solution 2

Edit Scheme -> Run -> Debug executable

Check this checkbox

this works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Set debug under Build Active Architecture Only to Yes

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I get this issue and the only way I could get it to work was to first run the app on terminal:

```
npx react-native run-ios
```

then reopen xcode and run it again..

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple versions of Xcode installed (including Xcode 14.3) you may need to perform the following song and dance:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72946533/731285