# Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS. Failed to boot device iPhone Xs

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder, ios-simulator, xcode10.3

I am getting an Error on the top of my interface builder in Xcode 10.3 and while clicking on report bug and checking the log.txt file I found out that fails to open simulator. However I am not starting any simulator.

Here is the Error found in Log.txt

```
Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS. (Failure reason: IBAgent-iOS failed to launch): Failed to boot device iPhone Xs (0B8270CC-2BFB-4BB6-90A5-6BA61468A1AD, iOS 12.4, Shutdown) for context <IBCocoaTouchToolLaunchContext: 0x7fe80e754ad0> toolName = IBAgent-iOS, description = <IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7fe80e2a0290> System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-ElevenAndLater <IBSimulatorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x7fe80fab2f90> deviceType=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-XS (Failure reason: Failed to boot iPhone Xs (0B8270CC-2BFB-4BB6-90A5-6BA61468A1AD, iOS 12.4, Shutdown)): Unable to boot the Simulator. (Failure reason: launchd failed to respond.)

Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=IBAgent-iOS failed to launch, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe80ae44440 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "Operation timed out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to boot iPhone Xs (0B8270CC-2BFB-4BB6-90A5-6BA61468A1AD, iOS 12.4, Shutdown), NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to boot device iPhone Xs (0B8270CC-2BFB-4BB6-90A5-6BA61468A1AD, iOS 12.4, Shutdown) for context <IBCocoaTouchToolLaunchContext: 0x7fe80e754ad0> toolName = IBAgent-iOS, description = <IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7fe80e2a0290> System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-ElevenAndLater <IBSimulatorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x7fe80fab2f90> deviceType=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-XS, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe80bd300f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "Operation timed out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=launchd failed to respond., NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to boot the Simulator.}}}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "IBAgent-iOS" for further information., NSLocalizedDescription=Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS.}
```

Comment: Hi Dipen I am facing the same issue, were you able to solve the problem. I am working on xcode 11.3 and in addition to this issue my simulator is not booting up once I run the project.

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: Same here. I can't even create new projects without facing this issue. Looks like maybe 11.3 broke something. Works fine in 11.2.

Comment: Solved similar issue, just install Windows and start developing for android os.

Answer (score 11):

If anyone still looking for an answer to this after Xcode 13 update, I have tried everything they mentioned on the internet and nothing worked except one. The only thing that worked is the complete re-installation of Xcode. Completely uninstall/delete Xcode first and restart the mac and reinstall Xcode then all should be good.

1. Delete Xcode from Applications Folder and Empty Trash.
2. Go to ~/Library/Developer and Delete CoreSimulator, Xcode, XCTestDevices Folder. Empty trash
3. Goto ~/Library/Caches and delete everything starting with com.apple.dt.Xcode, Empty trash

Then Restart your Mac and reinstall Xcode. I used my downloaded Xcode app, AppStore installation will also work, I guess.

Now it all working.

Before that, I have changed the storyboard file using `Open as Source Code` mode (coz I couldn't open it in Interface Builder - Xcode just hang)

I changed the storyboard design device to iPhone 13 instead of the older device version it had.

```
<device id="retina6_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
```

I change the existing line with this line. It kinda solve another issue of Xcode hanging, when trying to open with Interface Builder, but it didn't solve `Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS` issue when trying to install the app. That issue only got solved when I completely reinstalled the Xcode.

Comment: I've tried a few different things. When I first had this issue, I just had to clear out some old stuff in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport`. However when I found this issue again a few months later, nothing worked other than this suggestion (thanks!). I also used this link to help decide what to delete: https://izziswift.com/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-and-clear-all-settings/

Comment: This is already my third complete re-instalation of Xcode. Please no.

Comment: works like a charm . appreciated. i have not reinstall Xcode just do the 3 steps and restart mac andchanged the storyboard design device to iPhone 13 instead of the older device version it had.

Comment: the only way. that worked for me too

Answer (score 5):

I have managed to fix it just by changing preview device on interface builder

Answer (score 5):

In my case it helped:

- clean project
- remove derived data
- close Xcode
- restart Mac

Answer (score 1):

I used DevCleaner XC helper app:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/devcleaner-for-xcode/id1388020431?mt=12

removed everything, and after that restarted mac. No XC reinstall needed.

Answer (score -1):

This problem caused because, I deleted all directories under "Library/Developer/Xcode" for a purpose. But, I realised I also deleted wrong directories in same time. Then I put back directories from the Bin. It is solved for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you have or have had multiple versions of Xcode open, you may need to reboot or completely re-install the `CoreSimulatorService`, an evil, globally installed background service that somehow remains online and available to many versions of Xcode despite it being compatible with only one version.

See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72946533/731285

Other symptoms of this issue: Simulators not showing up in the `Window > Devices and Simulators` listing and `simctl` throwing errors and being unable to find base iOS SDKs similar to the following:

```
$ xcrun simctl list
...
-- Unavailable: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-5 --
    iPhone 8 (55A90310-8202-4A0D-968B-00F440D42210) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
```

See also:

- [Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52489500/731285)
- [Xcode device Unavailable, runtime profile not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180364/xcode-device-unavailable-runtime-profile-not-found)

Answer (score -1):

You can try to set development team in:

> Project > Targets > Signing & Capabilities > Team > Personal Team

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).